# Complicate integral

Tags: integration

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-x}\ln{x}\over 4-\cos{x}\cos2x\cos{4x}}dx$$

may have an answer of $-\ln{\zeta(3)}?$

$\zeta(3)=1.20205...$ :=[Apery constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant)

Any help to explain how is this integral is possible to produce an answer of $-\ln{\zeta(3)}$

Comment: Why do you think it has this answer?

Comment: i got this here $$-
 0.2352986276037121798201301460825458117714303437868945477353593300346271203013278678123462954114394605
$$

Comment: The answer is definitively not $r\times ln\left(\zeta(3)\right)$ , $r$ a rational number.

Comment: With *Mathematica* I get -0.184037679292898077258262783488 using `NIntegrate[
 Exp[-x] Log[x]/(4 - Cos[x] Cos[2 x] Cos[4 x]), {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 30, MaxRecursion -> 10]`.

Answer (score 3):

The numbers are close  but not the same.

Using something similar to what JimB did (requiring for more accuracy), I obtained for the integral
$$\color{red}{-0.18403}767929289807725826313633559065126820213619845$$ while $-\log (\zeta (3))$ is $$\color{red}{-0.18403}417539149142150495871104056237383272291847411$$ showing a difference of about $3.5 \times 10^{-6}$.